# maven lifecycle configuration

Tags: maven, plugins, lifecycle

I'm playing with maven plugins, specifically i'm trying to develop a custom maven plugin for eclipse. All goes well, it builds from console ... etc until:`

> "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration"

appears. I research and find this:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered;

obviously i do not want to ignore the plugin's execution, the execute instruction does not seem to work, as for the delegate to project configurator, i am not able to find

> AbstractJavaProjectConfigurator.java.

I've searched in org.eclipse.jdt , core and source but there is no reference to what i am searching, best match i could find was here:

http://git.eclipse.org/c/m2e/m2e-core.git/tree/org.eclipse.m2e.jdt/src/org/eclipse/m2e/jdt

All in one, what i want to achive is this: "Starting with m2e 1.1, maven plugin developers are able to provide lifecycle mapping metadata as part of the plugin itself." as stated in the first link i inserted. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simply bypass the mojo execution or telling m2e to simply execute your mojo via maven embedder you need the following:

1. a proper lifecycle mapping as explained in your link. Reference: https://github.com/php-maven/maven-php-plugin/blob/master/ide-plugins/eclipse/tags/2.0.3/org.phpmaven.eclipse.core/lifecycle-mapping-metadata.xml
   However I put it in the root of the eclipse project to be able to debug it (finding those extra resources sometimes failes if you put them in src folders).
2. A build properties to embedd it into build: https://github.com/php-maven/maven-php-plugin/blob/master/ide-plugins/eclipse/tags/2.0.3/org.phpmaven.eclipse.core/build.properties
3. Activation via dependencies and extension:

Hope this helps. I was confused about the project configurator too. But the above example does not require any project configurator.

Comment: This helps a bit. Further more when i installed Indigo with the new 1.0 m2e integration i got no more problems, besides the fact that eclipse wants to install JDT APT to fix the lifecycle mapping. And i do not even have the build.properties, unless it's generated somehow by eclipse, further more neither do i have the lifecycle-mapping-metadata.xml

Comment: I'm interested inthe following: http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_Extension_Development#AntlrProjectConfigurator_and_corresponding_metadata. As you can see there AntlrProjectConfigurator is using the class that I'm searching for. The reason i search for this dependency is that i suspect that you can map the lifecycles in code without  lifecycle-mapping-metadata.xml. Enlighten me, pls; can this be done?

Comment: the build.properties is generated if you edit the plugin.xml via the eclipse editor. There you have a tabpane "build properties". Actually it is only to include the lifecycle-mapping-metadata.xml within your jar file once you are building a feature/site and allow others to install it. To your second answer: As far as I know you cannot do it without a lifecycle-mapping-metadata.xml. At least the xml must contain a hint that you are wanting to use a project configurator. If you simply want your mojo to be executed you only need the xml and no java class.

Comment: so, let me get this straigth: 1. If I open the plugin.xml via eclipse editor, I'll have the lifecycles mapped, in the generated xml? 2. More data needed, regarding the ProjectConfiguratorl; i'll come back on this one